# Injecting a bean at runtime

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Can we inject a bean to a service during runtime? I'm working on a Spring MVC application and have two different beans which use the same functionality. I need to inject a bean during runtime based on some parameters. How do I do that in Spring?

Comment: where is the code ? Add the code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Runtime dependency injection with Spring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439839/runtime-dependency-injection-with-spring)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch between the beans which are already created 
then use this **method**

Autowire ApplicationContext in the class

```
@Autowired ApplicationContext ctx;
```

And in the method, just get those beans from the ApplicationContext and switch between those. I would use an interface and then have those 2 (or more) classes (which you want to switch at runtime) implement the interface so that there will be a contract.

```
BeanInterface beanName; 
if (x){
  beanName = (BeanClass1) ctx.getBean("beanClass1");
}
else{
  beanName = (BeanClass2) ctx.getBean("beanClass2");
}
```

**Disclaimer:** Did not test this out, you might need some tweaks if this is not working.

If you want even the bean creation to be based on certain runtime parameters, take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34350983/6785908