# Spring DI with dynamic constructor arguments

Tags: java, spring

Most of my classes wired up look something like:

```
@Component
public class MyClassImpl implements MyClass {

   private MyService service;

   @Autowired
   public MyClass(MyService service) {
      this.service = service;
   }
}
```

So that makes sense to me, but if I want to do something like this:

```
@Component
public class MyClassImpl implements MyClass {

   private MyService service;
   private String id;       // this is what I need

   @Autowired
   public MyClass(MyService service, String id) {
      this.service = service;
      this.id = id;
   }
}
```

But the problem is `String id` is not known until runtime.  Is there any way to do this?  From what I can tell, Spring checks all the dependencies by default at runtime so if I try the second example, it complains about the constructor arguments.

I've seen some examples where you can use a factory to create the actual value later down the line.  Or I can create getters and setters in order to set the `id` when I need it, but that would also mean I'd need to add those getters and setters to the interface `MyClass` as well.  Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: id is not dependency of the myclass, but its property. you cannot inject property

Comment: @IlyaBursov Oh ok that makes sense.

Comment: usually you should not mix properties and dependencies in one class, properties should be in pojos

Comment: @IlyaBursov Can you put those comments in an answer and i'll mark it closed. thanks.

Comment: I don't think it worth it, also - I could be wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid what you are trying to do is not in the spirit of what Spring was created for. Please do have a look at: [Runtime dependency injection with Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439839/runtime-dependency-injection-with-spring#1440017)

Having said that, there might be a workaround to your problem.
If you have some class that calculates that ID for you, just inject that class in a constructor and bind the result of its calculation to the field id in your class.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a @Bean method for id with logic needed to calculate it.

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public String idForService() {
        return calculateId();
    }
}
```

And then your service constructor will be look like this

```
   @Autowired
   public MyClass(MyService service, @Qualifier("idForService") String id) {
      this.service = service;
      this.id = id;
   }
```

But as others have already mentioned it looks like a bad practice so you'd better consider to redesign your service class.